# Splunk error specify atleast one named group

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am executing below splunk query.

```
index=api sourcetype=api-warn environ::api-prod* 
| bin _time span=1h
| rex mode=sed field=service_name "s#\..*$##" | rex field=requestPath "https://api.com.org.net/(abc)/(def)"
| stats count(service_name) by _time,service_name
```

Getting below error:

```
Error in 'rex' command: The regex 'https://api.com.org.net/(abc)/(def)' does not extract anything. It should specify at least one named group. Format: (?<name>...).
```

Suppose, one of the url is:

```
https://api.com.org.net/abc/def/some_number/?key=value&key=value
```

My regular expression:

```
https:\/\/(<api\.com\.org\.net\/abc\/def>*)
```

My regular expression does not match url, Could someone help out.

Not sure what is the issue here. I am using regex to match part of url abc/def in url'. Not sure what is going wrong. Can some one direct me in proper direction?

Answer (score 0):

The `rex` command requires at least one capture group of the form `(?<fieldname>...)` where 'fieldname' is a Splunk field name and '...' is a regular expression.  If you just want to filter data instead of extract fields, use the `regex` command, instead.